# Windows BAT: Find string occurrences across multiple files

Tags: batch-file, find, findstr

I have a set of text files all sitting in one folder. Call them `text1.txt`, `text2.txt` and `text3.txt`.

All these text files contain different text in them.

I want to be able to cycle through each of the files and count the number of occurrences of a particular string and output a results file which has the filename with the number of occurrences of that string.

e.g. I want to find the word "Microsoft". text1 contains it twice and text3 contains in once.

Output file would therefore show:

```
text1.txt 2
text3.txt 1
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You could use the [FIND](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/find.php) command. I'm no expert with batch, but I guess you could store the filenames in an array, loop through them, find the results (maybe by using a regex) and print them at the end.

Answer (score 3):

This is nearly your desired output:

`find /c "Microsoft" *.txt`

Answer (score 1):

The better results were when I used:

```
type *.txt | findstr "pattern"
```

Best regards,

Comment: yes this also shows where and how the "pattern" is used within a particular .txt file... thanksss